# C# Linq OrderBy

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to sort my customers by their last order by using `linq`.

`_list = _data.OrderBy(adress => adress.LastOrder.Date);`

My Problem here is, that for some customers the `LastOrder` is `NULL`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: do you want to include those customers or exclude them from the sorted list?

Comment: yes, i do want to include them

Comment: @sunny-boy - where should they sit in the list? Are you sorting these dates ascending or descending?

Comment: Is this just in-memory objects or EF or Linq-to-SQL?

Comment: Need to see your OrderBy_adress() method.

Comment: @sunny-boy - Can you also please make sure you've posted valid C# code in your question?

Comment: @Enigmativity it is just in memory

Comment: @sunny-boy - sorry, even after being asked multiple questions you've provided no clarity. This is a terrible question. Voting to close.

Comment: @sunny-boy - It's still not valid C# code.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ how can i make my question clearer to you?

Comment: By providing code that compiles?

Comment: @sunny-boy - It's still not correct code.

Comment: @sunny-boy - all you have to do is answer the questions we've asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
_list = _data.OrderBy(adress =>
    adress.LastOrder == null
        ? DateTime.MaxValue
        : adress.LastOrder.Date);
```

You need to choose between `DateTime.MaxValue` and `DateTime.MinValue` depending on how you want to order `null` items.

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle the null case:

```
var orderedByLastOrder = _data
    .OrderBy(x => x.LastOrder == null ? DateTime.MinValue : x.LastOrder.Date);
```